# Why are URL encoded values in $_GET variables broken?

Tags: 6

I'm working with a payment gateway that returns payment feedback in the URL. One of the variables has a special character in it:

```
PM=Sofort+%DCberweisung
```

The `%DC` is `Ü`. However, it's coming through instead as �—and in case that doesn't display properly here, it's a black triangle with a question mark inside it. I confirmed this by replacing my menu callback with a simple print and die:

```
print($_GET['PM']); die();
```

The output is just (again: I'm not sure how that broken character might appear here on StackExchange):

```
Sofort �berweisung (DE)
```

I have confirmed that if I replace the `%DC` in the URL with `Ü`, it prints fine, so it's not a problem with that character: something is going wrong, somewhere, when the server tries to decode the URL-encoded value.

Does Drupal do any kind of processing on `$_GET` variables during bootstrapping? Could this be an Apache configuration issue?

**Update:** This is definitely something in Drupal. I moved my print-then-die to the very beginning of `index.php` and it prints the correct value. This tells me that it's not an Apache problem. Then, on a clean D6 install with no contrib modules, I added a small module that just adds a single menu callback to do that same print-then-die, and I got the invalid character there.

Comment: This is definitely an encoding issue. It's fine if I run the variable through utf8_encode(), but I can't figure out where Drupal would be converting it from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Drupal performs no conversion on $_GET at all - %DC is just a byte sequence.  The conversion is being done by your browser, and it's triggered by the presence of the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the head.  When you die() right away in index.php, you prevent the charset meta element from being output, so your browser guesses ISO-8859 and you see Ü.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your incoming data is ISO-8859-1, not the other way round. Drupal is *always* in UTF-8 (and utf8_encode converts *from* ISO-8859-1 to UTF8).

This is what I get when urlencoding Ü.:

```
$ drush ev 'var_dump(urlencode('ü'));'
string(6) "%C3%BC"
```

And when urldecoding *and* utf8 encoding %DC:

```
$ drush ev "var_dump(utf8_encode(urldecode('%DC')));"
string(2) "Ü"
```

Makes all perfect sense to me.